# Android custom horizontal progress bar bitmap drawable gets stretched

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, progress-bar

I am using custom progress bar drawable for horizontal progress bar in Android application. It is a two-leyered drawable. First layer is diagonally striped png image with `tileMode="repeat"`. Second layer adds shadow over the stripes. This is how the progress_bar_horizontal.xml drawable looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
      <clip>
        <layer-list>
          <item>
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/diagonal_stripes_0" android:tileMode="repeat" />
          </item>
          <item>
            <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/inset_shadow" />
          </item>
        </layer-list>
      </clip>
    </item>
    </layer-list>
```

This drawable is used in theme to restyle the progress bar control:

```
    <style name="Theme.Custom" parent="android:Theme.Light">
      <item name="android:progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal.Custom</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal.Custom" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_inset_gray</item>
      <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_bar_horizontal</item>
      <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_bar_indeterminate_horizontal</item>
    </style>
```

The idea is to make a diagonnally-striped progress bar which does not strerch, but grows in width as the operation progresses. That is why `<clip>` is used.

It works fine most of the time. However from time to time (without any chances to reproduce on purpose) it starts to stretch single tile of the drawable instead of clipping it appropriately.

The application is developed with `android:minSdkVersion="7"` and running on HTC Desire with Android 2.2.

Any help would be appreciated.